# Taking a list of integers in groups of three and outputting them in groups of 8

Tags: java, list, groovy, output

i am working on a few exercises to do with parallel using the groovy plugin in java however i have hit a wall. The system takes data objects that contain three integers but has to output the data in objects that contain integers.

What iv got so far:

```
import org.jcsp.lang.*

class GenerateSetsOfThree implements CSProcess {

    def ChannelOutput outChannel

    void run(){
        def threeList = [
                         [1, 2, 3], 
                         [4, 5, 6], 
                         [7, 8, 9], 
                         [10, 11, 12], 
                         [13, 14, 15], 
                         [16, 17, 18],
                         [19, 20, 21], 
                         [22, 23, 24] ]
        for ( i in 0 ..< threeList.size)outChannel.write(threeList[i])
        //write the terminating List as per exercise definition
        outChannel.write ([-1, -1, -1])
```

this all works fine.
Then:

```
import org.jcsp.lang.*

class ListToStream implements CSProcess{

    def ChannelInput inChannel
    def ChannelOutput outChannel

    void run (){
        def inList = inChannel.read()
        while (inList[0] != -1) {
            // hint: output list elements as single integers
        outChannel.write (inList[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

        }
        outChannel.write(-1)
    }
}
```

This is where the issue arises, i have no idea how to take the integers and group them into eights

finally:

```
import org.jcsp.lang.*

class CreateSetsOfEight implements CSProcess{

    def ChannelInput inChannel

    void run(){
        def outList = []
        def v = inChannel.read()
        while (v != -1){
            for ( i in 0 .. 7 ) {
                // put v into outList and read next input
                outList = [(v)]
                v = inChannel.read()    
            }
            println " Eight Object is ${outList}"
        }
        println "Finished"
    }
}
```

this all seems fine.

Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking for help with. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: My issue is in the class ListtoStream, where i need to output the list elements as single integers. I need output eight elements from threeList. the code i added was :   outChannel.write (inList[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]). this just gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not supposed to convert them in `ListToStream` to octuples already.  first they get converted to single values there.  the convertion to octuples is done in the last step `CreateSetsOfEight`.  to pass down single values, you emit each value on its own.

e.g.

```
while (inList[0] != -1) {
    // hint: output list elements as single integers
    inList.each{ outChannel.write it }
    inList = inChannel.read()
}
```

Yet all the anwers are online too: https://github.com/GPars/GPars/tree/master/docs/JonKerridgeBook

Comment: okay that clears things up a bit, do you have any examples of how to do this? i'm still new to this so i'm not quite clear on all the syntax.

Comment: don't you want to try first for yourself.  what good is the exercise then?

Comment: I wasn't asking for the answer directly, just pointed in the right direction.

Comment: iterate over inlist and emit to the outchannel

Comment: Based upon what you said i tried a variety of different methods, i tried outChannel.write(inList) this only gave me the first three objects. Next i tried outChannel.write(inList[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) which gave me the first three objects followed by a series of nulls. Any other suggestions?